# Kinect raw depth to distance in meters

Tags: kinect, depth

I am trying to convert Kinect depth map to distance in meters. The problem is that for depthmap value '1080' and around it, distance is too large because the term in denominator becomes very close to '0'. and for values above '1090', distance is negative.

```
if (depthValue < 2047) 
{
  depthM = 1.0 / (depthValue*-0.0030711016 + 3.3309495161);
}
```

Comment: Are you using the Kinect SDK? The depth map there is in milli meters and does not need to be converted. Please give a little more detail to your question.

Comment: i know that i can get depth in 'mm' directly but i have some old depth images, which have raw depth values provided by Kinect (they range from 0 to more than 8000). I am not using Kinect or OpenNi SDK. i just need to convert those raw values to their respective depth values in 'm'. On many sites the above function is mentioned for this conversion but this formula is definitely not correct for values above 1080

Answer (score 5):

The correct answer is actually a comment on your question. The number given is actually a distance in millimetres. To get this number, you either need to use a skeleton joint and call DepthImageFrame's MapFromSkeletonPoint or shift the raw short value right by DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmaskWidth.

E.g. Skeleton

```
using (var skeletonFrame= e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
using (var depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
{
    skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
    var skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];

    foreach (var skeleton in skeletons)
    {
            if (skeleton.TrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked) continue;

            var head = skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head];
            if (head.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked) continue;

            var depthImagePoint = depthFrame.MapFromSkeletonPoint(head.Position);

            int depthInMillimeters = depthImagePoint.Depth; // TADA!
    }
}
```

E.g. shift

```
using (var depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
{
    var depthArray = new short[depthFrame.PixelDataLength];
    depthFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(depthArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < depthArray.Length; i++) {
        int depthInMillimeters = 
            depthArray[i] >> DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmaskWidth;
        // TADAx2!
}
```

**The original solution below is no longer correct:**

Based on the contents of this article - http://openkinect.org/wiki/Imaging_Information:

```
if (depthValue <= 2047) {
   depthM = 0.1236 * Math.Tan(depthValue / 2842.5 + 1.1863);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

old inactive question but anyway here is what worked for me I have an old model of kinect (1414 for XBOX360 + PC reduction) and recently had time to make some code and measurements:

1. **my raw data is 16 bit not 10/11/12/13 bit !!!**

   so probably your data is very similar. Min distance measured is `~0.95m` max distance unknown (have not big enough area for testing) and min valid value is `6408 ... ~0.95m` from sensor . Another valid value is `15800 ... ~2.5m` from sensor for interpolation
2. **naive (linear) transformation to meters**

   ```cpp
   float z,m=(2.5-0.9)/(15800.0-6408.0);
   WORD raw;

   raw=... raw depth form camera/image;
   z=0.0;
   if ((raw>=6408)&&(raw< 0xFFF0)) 
    z=0.9+(float(raw-6408)*m);
   // here z is range in [m] or 0 for invalid depth
   ```
3. **when I will have more time then I will check the linearity and make it more precise**

   to do that I need to make some programing for better measurement and setup working area for more precise distance measurements. More precise constants maybe add cosine correction if its needed. I do not know if device/driver make it itself or not have to measure it. When I get to it will update my answer but I am very lazy so it can be a while ...

**[Edit 1] made some geometry measurement setup and code changes**
so here are new more precise conclusions:

```cpp
if (raw==0x0000) z=0.0;
else if (p.raw>=0x8000) p.z=4.0;
else p.z=0.8+(float(p.raw-6576)*0.00012115165336374002280501710376283);
```

`raw` data is already cosine corrected by driver or **kinect** itself so `raw` represent perpendicular distance from sensor. `raw` data is linear to perpendicular distance (at least on 0.8 - 2.0 m range) and after more precise measurement the depth range is `<0.8 - 4.0> [m]`. Measurements before was inaccurate.

`raw = 0` is too close value

`raw >= 32768` is too far / unknown value or even something else (there are more possibilities)

Comment: @shshadi I store kinect data as list of points struct pnt3d { float x,y,z; WORD raw; DWORD *rgb; } p; where x,y,z is position of pixel respect to kinect, raw is coresponding value from RAW Depth-frame and *rgb is pointer to coresponding pixel in RGB frame  ... z is the perpendicular distance from kinect