# OpenGL create a projection matrix similar to the kinect camera

Tags: opengl, matrix, camera, projection-matrix

I want to create a perspective projection matrix in OpenGL. This projection matrix should simulate the kinect camera from Xbox One. It should be the depth camera from the kinect. It should be as exactly as possible.

I am using for the moment this:

```
matrix = glm::perspective(70.6f, 1.177f, 0.01f, 1700.0f);
```

I found for the kinect camera that it has a field of view of 70.6 in x and 60 in y. So I thought it would work by just giving as angle  70.6 and as aspect ration 1.177, which is 70,6/60.

What would be an accurate way to define such a projection matrix?

Comment: Define "accurate"? Are you just searching for a projection matrix, fitting the aspect of the Kinect camera, because then it sounds like you're on the right track (granted your values are correct).

Comment: I need this projection matrix for reconstruction of an object out of the depth maps. So to proper find the correct pixel coordinate I need an accurate projection.

Comment: the easiest way is to set your **OpenGL** view area to the size of **kinect** frame this way you get rid of the `FOVx/FOVy` angle difference. Your `FOVx` is quite a bit different then mine are you sure you are measuring single camera?  Take a look at these: [Kinect raw depth to distance in meters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19876643/2521214) , [Does Kinect Infrared View Have an offset with the Kinect Depth View](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19905805/2521214) , [Align already captured rgb and depth images](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35914008/2521214). The FOV can change with resolution of Kinect

Comment: I have the kinect one. My sources are from: http://smeenk.com/kinect-field-of-view-comparison/

Comment: @Dominick you need to measure it on target resolution as device to device can have different properties (both FOV and offset). Manufactor declared value is not safe to use ... also Kinect one is hardly enough determination you need to look at the version number on the bottom there is a stamp usually ... there were  big difference between some versions I got one of the first generation with different FOVs and raw data formats, ranges etc ...