# Kinect V2 depth in metres - Processing 3.x

Tags: image-processing, processing, kinect, kinect-sdk, openkinect

I am using Processing 3.3.6 with the openkinect library (link below). I have a Kinect V2 sensor, and as given in the examples in the below link, I am getting the depth values from a `depth[]` array.

[Openkinect Library for Processing](http://shiffman.net/p5/kinect/)

The link above gives the formula given for converting the raw depth value to depth value in meters in real world.

`depthInMeters = 1.0 / (rawDepth * -0.0030711016 + 3.3309495161);`

This is adapted from here :[Depth in meters calculation](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/Kinect.html)

I am getting values ranging from `0 - 4500`, and after applying the formulae from the above references, the values after conversion to meters are not accurate, they are off by about `70m`. So, is there any other way or method to convert the depth to meters. Should I only use the official development environment like Visual Studio (C++ , C#) with the SDK for calculating depth?
Or can open source tools like Processing be used to capture the values albeit with a different approach? Help or guidance would be appreciated as it is a completely new area for me so far.

Comment: did you correctly calibrate your Kinect device?

Comment: @ Master Yushi: Yup, I have calibrated using GML C++ Camera Calibration. From [Kinect depth in meters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824743/kinect-raw-depth-to-distance-in-meters), it says the above formula is not correct. I also get negative values in the depth. Any correction to the above formula or resources would be appreciated.

Comment: @WilbusFugu measure few rawdepths for known distances and compute the formula from that ... We do not have your device so we do not know the parameters. Each device has its own constants.... You also should plot a graph for those measurements to see if the output is linear or not, do this in forward and side direction to see if your data is fish eye corrected or not (for mine Kinect v1 are. see [Kinect raw depth to distance in meters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19876643/2521214) more info)