# Transforming coordinates on Kinect image

Tags: image, math, image-processing, transform, kinect

My situation looks like this:
[image]

So, I have a table. There will be some items on a table, let's say- oranges. There is a projector right above a table and kinect hanging on some angle (the position of kinect and table will never change).

I want to catch images from kinect every 1 second (easy), then search for oranges on it (easy) and then draw circles around oranges + put pink background on table using projector (some kind of AR, this is the hard part). How can I transform coordinates that I`ll get from Kinect so that projector puts image right on table? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options. The first is to find the corners of the table in Kinect image and interpolate from that something like this:

- [OpenCV Birdseye view without loss of data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39316776/2521214)

The other one is create [transform matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) representing either the projection plane or the projector itself and convert your 3D position local to kinect to the table or projector local coordinates.

Anyway these might get handy:

- [Align already captured rgb and depth images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35914008/2521214)
- [Kinect raw depth to distance in meters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19876643/2521214)